# NULL when casting string values to decimal in Hive

Tags: hadoop, replace, casting, hive, decimal

I'm using Hive 0.13 and I have in a STRING column of my table values like 1.250,99
I want to cast these values into decimal, so I must replace "." by "" and "," by "." The result would be 1250.99 
This is my hql sentence:

```
cast(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(price, '\\.',''), ',','.') as decimal(18,6))
```

But it returns NULL, I suppose because the conversion does not succeed. What is the problem?
If I don't do the conversion, it returns the expected string.

UPDATE

My problem was that there were white spaces in the column, so it could not convert it into decimal value. I have used trim function before doing the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select cast(regexp_replace(regexp_replace('1.234,56','\\.',''),'\,','\.') as decimal(10,2));
```